# HTML element positioning - How do I have an element always stay in the visible area without javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a small widget on a web page such that when the page loads in a maximized window, the element appears to be inline.

When the vertical scroll bar moves down, the element scrolls up until it hits the top visible line of the browser control. Thereafter if you scroll further down, this elements sticks at the top border of the browser.

In other words, if there is enough screen area and if it can be visible on the current window, it appears inline and the moment its inline position goes out of the visible window due to scroll, this elements sticks to the border it hit and stays there until the scroll brings its inline position back into the visible window.

I need to achieve this purely via CSS only - no javascript. Any idea how this could be done?

Thanks in advance for looking this post up.

Comment: Can simply make that HTML element `position: fixed`

Comment: No. The answer is no. But tell me, why don't you want to use Javascript?

Comment: My widget is an iframe inside a Zoho Creator view. Zoho Creator allows only HTML - it strips off any javascript. I hate this stripping off of javascript, but can't do much about it. Hence trying to achieve this via CSS.

Comment: Thanks @SilverBlade. Not exactly what I want but an acceptable compromise as it comes close.

Comment: Thanks @MoizTankiwala for your appreciation. I have made this as the answer. You can suggest the modification required :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your view with position: fixed, so that it remains on the visible area.

```
.selector {
   position: fixed;
   /* rest required styling */
}
```